# Why cant I re-enable an element in a document after disabling the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im having a real problem getting a load of inputs in a table to allow selection after I have disabled selection for the document. I dont want horrible blue select range (I am makign my own select range using css). So I want to get rid of it. But I need selection to be enabled on certain inputs. Only problem is when I disable the selection on a document then try and re-enable inouts whithin the document it doesnt work. Individually disabling selection on the table cells doesnt work properly either every now anad again you can accidently select a range of cells...

UPDATE : This is specifically for IE. I basically want to disable all highlight, or at worst disable all highlighting of the table. Then I want to enable highlighting in certain cells. Im creating a spreadsheet application. I dont want any blue. I want to control what is highlighted. Sorry if the above wasn't clear.

Hope someone can help...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="/Content/Fiddle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <h2>Javascript Fiddle</h2>
            <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                disableSelection(document.body);
                //enable certain elements
                var selectableElements = jQuery('.highlightable');
                jQuery.each(selectableElements, function (key, value) {
                    enableSelection(this);
                });
            });

            function disableSelection(target) {
                if (typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined") //IE route  
                {
                    target.onselectstart = function () {
                        return false;
                    };
                }
                else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") //Firefox route                  
                    target.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
                else //All other route (ie: Opera)                  
                    target.onmousedown = function () { return false; };
                try {
                    target.style.cursor = "default";
                }
                catch (ex) {
                }
            }

            function enableSelection(target) {
                if (typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined") { //IE route                  
                    target.onselectstart = function () {
                        return true;
                    };
                }
                else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") //Firefox route                  
                    target.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
                else //All other route (ie: Opera)                  
                    target.onmousedown = function () { return false; };

                target.style.cursor = "default";
            }
            </script>
            <div id="tableHolder">
                <table>
                    <tr><td>abc 12 3</td><td class="highlightable"><input id="testSelection" value="dblClickMe" type="text" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>abc 12 3</td><td><input class="highlightable" type="text" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>abc 12 3</td><td><input class="highlightable" type="text" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>abc 12 3</td><td><input class="highlightable" type="text" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <script src="/Scripts/Fiddle.js" type="text/javascript"  ></script> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to enable anything within a document that is itself disabled. What are you trying to do, exactly? Why do you `disableSelection(document.body);`?

Comment: Please see the above. I want to disable the blue highlighting apart from in an input element.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with CSS for some browsers: [user-select: none;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/user-select). since you're already using jQuery, I can offer this piece of code I use in [jQuery.contextMenu](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/) (modified for your needs):

```
function abortevent(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
};

if($.browser.msie) {
    $(document).on('selectstart.disableTextSelect', 'td', abortevent);
} else if(!$.browser.mozilla) {
    $(document).on('mousedown.disableTextSelect', 'td', abortevent);
}
```

Comment: that's why my answer provides a javascript fallback…